# Extjs 4 drag and drop proxy z-index issue

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I've placed panel from this example
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html
to Ext.window.Window and got an issue: proxy tooltip (1 selected row) is now showing behind the Window. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce behavior you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/8sbRr/ 
The tool tip is hiding as soon as the green arrows appear indicating a valid drop target. It definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: looks like the zindex drops from 29000 to 19001